# Graphical Workflow using Java

Tags: java, workflow, business-process-management

I recently (not my choice..) developed a perl application that handle batch process workflow. This application has its own workflow specification.
The second part of the application is to create a GUI showing the process workflow (with box and process states..).
I had a look on products such as Activi or jBPM, but those contain engine that does not fit my need. I just need a tools that can dynamiccaly draw a workflow given some instruction (such as XML...).

Do you have any idea about products, that can display BPM graphic without any engine ?

Thanks !

Comment: Most of the BPM products will have engines built into it. Are you looking for purely a drawing tool ?

Comment: Yeap, as the workflow process is done by a perl program, I don't need the engine. So I think, deploying a BPM engine would be a little bit oversized. Maybe a drawing tool / framework designed to draw workflow would be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a suitable tool for you? It uses a simple markup (or GXL, which, according to them, is "an XML dialect") to define your graph. Here is [one example](http://www.graphviz.org/content/cluster), (the [Gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) contains more examples). Several different [output formats](http://www.graphviz.org/content/output-formats) are supported, including .bmp, .jpg, .png.

Comment: Thanks for your answer matsev, I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

[Bonitasoft](http://www.bonitasoft.org/)? It does have an engine but can also output bpmn and several other formats.